# Magento get the product image types (image, thumbnail, small_image)

Tags: magento

I am retriving product details by id:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
```

I need to get product image details using below function:

```
$images = $model->getMediaGalleryImages();
```

But i am not getting the image type (image, thumbnail, small_image).

Can anyone please help me how to get this image types.

Thank You so much.

Answer (score 2):

you can get image

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
echo $model->getImage();
        echo "<br>";
        echo $model->getSmallImage();
        echo "<br>";
        echo $model->getThumbnail();
        echo "<br>";
        echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($model, 'small_image')->resize(163,100); // resize function is used to resize image
        echo "<br>";
        echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($model, 'image')->resize(400,400);
```

Comment: Hi Thank You for the reply. But below values are not coming.
echo $model->getImage();
echo $model->getSmallImage();
echo $model->getThumbnail();

Any idea why this is happening. Thank you again.

Comment: did you set the default image? this code for default images.

Comment: What about the "non_selected" images can we get them too?

Comment: @Xabby here is how it works you set other image exclude checkbox true and gallery image you will  use the exclude checkbox false

Comment: @QaisarSatti Actually there are two places where i showing image gallery. one is under the product image and other one i have created the banner at the top. so if i exclude them images will stop showing both of the galleries. check this one:
http://usatilea.nextmp.net/index.php/materials/ceramic/love-charm/love-charm-grey-14x40-11-55-s.html

Comment: @Xabby exclude image will be shown in boths  media gallery. try it first

Answer (score 1):

this will help you.

for thumbnail you can try this.

```
Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($item->getProduct(), 'thumbnail');
```

for images:

```
Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(265);
```

for small images you can try this:

```
Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(163, 100);
```

**I hope this will help you.**